# Enable Bookmarks of PDF using IFrame

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, vbscript

I am able to display the PDF using the IFrame.but,I need to enable the bookmarks using the code.I know if I right click on the PDF i can enable the bookmarks.I need the bookmarks to show when the PDF is shown.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the initial view properties of the pdf file, or indicate it on the url loaded into the iframe as

```
http://somewhere.com/file.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked smooth

Comment: It doesn't work here in Chrome. But it works in Firefox.

Comment: @kikov: have you tried to disable the internal chrome pdf viewer?

Comment: @MCND I would like to inform that the implementation of URL to PDF links are related to the viewer, and Chrome internal pdf viewer is not implementing that functionality. If the author of the question is looking for an universal solution, this is not working.

Comment: @Kikov: that is the reason for the question in the previous comment. The answer was based on the documentation of the Adobe Reader URL parameters. And independently of the management of parameters in URL, the plugin author can decide not to implement the bookmark management, or can have a programmed behaviour of not showing the bookmarks for a pdf that has been viewed and for which bookmarks were closed, or .... Now, multiply it for the implementations in of each plugin for each supported browser. There is a lot of elements that can make it fail. But, this is the usual method to do it work.