# How to preview PDF files in a browser with CHAPTERS in the side using PHP code

Tags: php, pdf

i want to include the chapters, OR pages, OR bookmarks on the side of the preview of my pdf file whenever i view them in my browser is that possible ? .. 
this is the code i found somewhere in previewing pdf file

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="900" height="500"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openPdf()
  {
    var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    omyFrame.style.display="block";
    omyFrame.src = "myFile.pdf";
  }
</script>
```

is it possible to show the chapters on the left side just like the design whenever i open adobe reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a paremeter in the PDF URL with "#" after the filename.

The question is already answered:
[Enable Bookmarks of PDF using IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054847/enable-bookmarks-of-pdf-using-iframe/20055311)

You could use the parameters to the url to open the pdf file:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="900" height="500"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openPdf()
  {
    var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    omyFrame.style.display="block";
    omyFrame.src = "myFile.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks";
  }
</script>
```

It won't work in Chrome dued to the following bug [64309](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309):

There are a lot of available parameters like "view", "scrollbars",.. that you can read in the [SDK Doc](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)